# How to make this message in my app to be well arrange in textview?

Tags: android, textview

But this is how I want it to look like:

[image]

I'd be glad if anyone can help me with getting it fixed.

Comment: What does your app look like at present, and what problem are you having **specifically**?

Comment: I'm having problem of the text not well arrange or look the way I want it to be... As you can see the picture I have put here .. I want it to be arrange in number.

Comment: I guess you are statically defining yout text in xml layout file, just add '\n' before every numbered line.

Comment: Oh thanks , it seems to work but how can I make paragraph ? The numbers now start from the right accordinally . but there is no space in btw the text. I'd like to know what to do to make paragraph. Thanks alot